# Get Network Signal Strength From Raspberry Pi Using Java

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I need to get the WiFi signal strength and save it in a file.

I have tried this code but it is unable to create or execute the `iwconfig` command:

```java
try {
    String cmd = "sudo iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i --color signal>/home/pi/signal.txt";
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);  
    p.waitFor();
}
catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {             
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No Exception is Thrown.
The result should be like the result of the command should be store in signal.txt
If the file doesn't exist it'll create one and write. If exist it will overwrite in the file.

If I ran the `sudo iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i --color signal>/home/pi/signal.txt` in the terminal it is working correctly.
But if I execute it from Java it is not working.

The same process is used to delete a file in a different module. But this deletion working fine. But the File is not creating in the system

```
      String cmd = "rm signal.txt"; 
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        p.waitFor();
```

Comment: You have to provide more details. Is it throwing an Exception? How do you start your java program?

Comment: What is the specific error you are getting? Is an exception being thrown? What is the output of the command?

Comment: Are you sure that exec() runs the command inside a shell? You rely on shell features like | and >, but i can't see anything in the Javadoc to indicate that those are actually "allowed " / supported.

Comment: @Taschi-corporationsarebad good point. This would at least require a `bash -c 'my command here'` to solve.

Comment: No Exception is throwing @Mas @ J. Schultke and The Output should be a file created in named signal.txt. But it is not Creating or if the file does exist it is not writing in it. If I ran those command (sudo iwconfig wlan0 | grep -i --color signal>/home/pi/signal.txt)  in terminal it is working fine